# how to update the date field for this specific condition using oracle query?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I want to update one date column in oracle table for the below scenario...

1. currentYR=Get the Current Year from the SYSDATE (2015)
2. currentYR=currentYR-2(2013)
3. **Need to set date field like 01-JUN-13(Last TWO DIGITS OF currentYR(2013)**

Basically i just want to set set date like year=2 years earlier from sysdate and month=june,date=1. and date format is like DD-MON-YY(01-JUN-13)

Please guide me to resolve this problem.

Comment: Please show your COMPLETE sql statement.  Your question is unclear.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve here? Do you just want to set the date to the 1st of June 2013 or do you want to set the date to 2 years earlier regardless what date you have in the column?

Comment: @gvenzl:yes i just want to set the date to the 01-JUN-13(LAST TWO DIGIT OF currentYR)

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
update yourtable
set yourcolumn = add_months(sysdate, -24)
```

`-24` means 2 years earlier

Comment: @RubahMalam : i want to set set date like year=2 years earlier from sysdate and month=june,date=1. and date format is like DD-MON-YY(01-JUN-13)

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comment above I think you would like to set the value of the column to a date where only the last two digits of the year are provided. You can do so by using a [Datetime format model](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/sql_elements004.htm#SQLRF00212) reflecting this:

```
UPDATE <your table> SET <yourcolumn> = TO_DATE('01-JUN-13','DD-MON-YY') WHERE ...;
```

Comment: i want to set set date like year=2 years earlier from sysdate and month=june,date=1. and date format is like DD-MON-YY(01-JUN-13)

Answer (score 0):

Finally found the answer. This is the query which i wanted...

```
SELECT ADD_MONTHS (TRUNC (SYSDATE, 'YEAR'), -19 ) FROM DUAL;

QUERY RESULT

01-JUN-13
```